# MSBuild from TeamCity ignores DeployIISAppPath

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, webdeploy

In TeamCity I have created build step that is running MSBuild with target Package(not my script just MSBuild runner from TC pointing to csproj), then this package is deployed through web deploy to iis.

Problem is that deployment is creating new application under Default Web Site and I would like to deploy it to one already existing.
So I added parameter to build **DeployIISAppPath=Default Web Site\ MySite** and I have checked that in generated **SetParameters** file it actually is **Default Web Site\ MySite** but still this value is ignored and app is deployed to **XXX_deploy** virtual directory created by deploy.

Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried what's described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233496/what-is-expected-for-deployiisapppath-setting-on-msbuild-argument).  And are your paths quoted because you've got spaces in them?

Comment: What type of parameter did you create in TeamCity?  You'll need to use a System Property parameter.